# ext js combobox boundlist pagesize pagination ui does not appear

Tags: extjs, combobox, pagination

Expected: the boundlist pageSize property >0 makes the pagination UI appear at the bottom of the combobox dropdown.

Actual: the UI does not appear.

I read about this in the ExtJS documentation but this option doesn't appear to be working at all?

adding a pageSize property to the boundlist as described over here should add a pagination UI.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.view.BoundList.html#cfg-pageSize

So overriding this boundlist should be done like this?

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-listConfig

Either this or the floatedPicker option (so replace listConfig with floatedPicker).

But neither of these options appear to work, backend already supports search and pagination. I just can't this pagination bar to appear at all.

Here is an older version example:
http://skirtlesden.com/articles/extjs-comboboxes-part-2

store in model:

```
taskconfiguration: {
  model: "TaskConfiguration",
  autoLoad: true,
  pageSize: 25,
  proxy: {
    type: "customapi",
    url: `${Ext.manifest.base_url}taskconfiguration`,
    reader: {
      rootProperty: "data",
      type: "json",
    },
  },
},
```

component in view:

```
{
  xtype: "combobox",
  valueField: "id",
  displayField: "description",
  pageSize: 25,
  queryMode: "remote",
  listConfig: {                     
    pageSize: 25,                     
  },
  localized: {
    label: "{choosetaskconfiguration}",
  },
  bind: {
    store: "{taskconfiguration}",
    value: "{record.taskconfigurationid}",
    disabled: "{!buildingAndTaskConfigEditable}",
    required: "{buildingAndTaskConfigEditable}",
  },
  listeners: {
    select: "selectedTaskConfiguration",
  },
},
```

EDIT:

Seems like they also have plugins for data views, so you might work around this by just using one of those I guess... Or make your own plugin...

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.dataview.plugin.ListPaging.html

Comment: Are you sure that pagination is correctly configured between ExtJS and your backend? For example can you view the data with a `grid` using `pagingtoolbar`? Your code seems to be good, I have similar and it works with classic toolkit.

Comment: Try to add the store to the combo without binding, see if it works that way. This is perfectly working for me: `xtype: 'combobox',  store: {  model: 'MyModel', autoLoad: true, proxy: {  type: 'myproxy',  url: 'myurl' },    pageSize: 10  }, listConfig: { pageSize: 10},`